# Hibernate: "ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil"

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, annotations

My application is trying to use Hibernate annotations. I've gotten the 3.5.0 version of Hibernate installed, but when I try to load my app I get the following exception:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testSubscriber (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.findAllProviders(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
    at com.upod.dao.SubscriberDAOTest.<init>(SubscriberDAOTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:58)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:280)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.getTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit3TestLoader.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:399)
    ... 22 more
)
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:90)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

Apprently, I'm missing something, or I have incompatible jars *again*, but for the life of me I can't figure out where the problem  is. I've got the hibernate3.jar, ejb3-persistence.jar, and all of the dependencies specified in the Hibernate docs, yet I still get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the correct JPA jar in your classpath?  since youre error is: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil`

**EDIT**

Y'know, before we go further trying to figure this out, we should ask if it's really necessary to be using 3.5.0 (since at the time of this writing, it's 3.5.0-**Beta**-2).  If all you're looking for is Annotations, using Hibernate Core 3.3.2 is enough to allow you to use Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.

IMHO, you might want to just back up a version to something "safe"

Comment: The only JPA jar I know of is the ejb3-persistence.jar, and I do have it on my classpath. The class that is not found is not defined in that jar.

Comment: Hmmm, where did that `ejb3-persistence.jar` come from? is it JPA 2.0 ?

Comment: Near as I can tell, that jar is necessary to define the annotations for a JPA application. If I remove it, I get compile errors for @Entity, etc...

Comment: Actually, its not necessary to use 3.5.0, but when I went back to the 3.3.2 version I got other missing classes (ReflectionManager I believe was one of them). I used 3.5.0, since it seemed that all the dependencies were included so there was less chance of me missing a jar file :-)

Comment: Ok, so I moved back to the 3.3.2 version. When I run my testcases now, I get an exception saying that org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager is not found. 

Same problem, different jar...

Comment: well that one can be solved by including hibernate-commons-annotations jar.  -- Are you using Maven by any chance?

Comment: I found the hibernate-commons-annotations.jar and included it. Tha solved the hibernate problems. Unfortunately, I'm still having other class path issues, but I'll wade through those and see if I can't figure them out...

Thanks for the help...

Comment: Steve, see Srini's answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821553/yet-another-hibernate-question/2309818#2309818. This import is needed for the new version of Hibernate.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Hibernate 3.5.x, you also need the following jar file.

**`hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0-CR-1.jar`**

I had the same problem and adding this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what documentation you are referring to as you didn't post any link so I didn't check what it is saying but I think that you you are missing the `jpa-api` dependency   that I can see in the [pom.xml](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-parent/3.5.0-Beta-2/hibernate-parent-3.5.0-Beta-2.pom) of `hibernate-parent-3.5.0-Beta-2` (it provides `javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil`):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-cr-1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can get it from the [JBoss Maven](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/java-persistence/jpa-api/2.0-cr-1/jpa-api-2.0-cr-1.jar) repository (it doesn't seem to be included in the   bundle released on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.5.0-Beta-2/)). Time to start using maven :)